# Error with filemanager in controller

Tags: opencart

I want to show 40 images in image upload

I am also trying to change the pagination in controller/file manager.php from 16 to 36 and when I am running this then getting error

unexpected Syntex class commonController in line 1

what may be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Please modify filemanager.php under admin\controller. Replace 16 with 40 and 14 with 40-2= 38. 
You can increase as many images per page as you can. I have put in upto 144 and working like a charm.

Please do not forget to refresh Modifications for every change otherwise you dont see the changes.

Raj